# r leaflet limit max zoom with markerClusterOptions turned on

Tags: r, leaflet, zooming

I have a leaflet map, which has points that overlap when zoomed out. I have therefore used `markerClusterOtions()` so that as the user zooms in, the overlapping points that were grouped into clusters will separate.

This is all working fine, but my problem is that I would like to apply a zoom limit.  I don't want the users to be able to zoom right in to street level, because then they could see the exact address of my markers (which in this case would be a data protection issue).  I want the markers to freeze when the user reaches the max zoom limit, but until then, they should keep separating out as the user zooms in.

I thought this could be achieved by setting the `maxZoom` in `tileOptions`, and `freezeAtZoom` in markerClusterOptions, but it doesn't work and I keep getting a strange error.

Here is my code:

```
# Create the interactive map:
myleaflet <- leaflet() %>% 
  # Add open street map (default base layer)
  addTiles(tileOptions(minZoom = 1, maxZoom = 12)) %>% 
  # Add transformed shapefile of regions
  addPolygons(data = regions, weight = 5, col = "black") %>% 
  # Add markers for case residence with descriptive labels:
  addMarkers(lng = mydata$home_long,
             lat = mydata$home_lat,
             popup = paste("ID: ", mydata$id, "<br/>",
                           "Link: ", mydata$links, "<br/>", 
                           "Clade: ", mydata$wgs_cluster), 
             clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(freezeAtZoom = "max")) 

# View the map:
myleaflet
```

And here is the error I get (it appears when I try to view the map, not when running the code to create it):

```
Error in dirname(to) : path too long
```

If I remove the zoom options, I can view the map, but then the zoom is not limited.

I have looked at posts regarding this error, and I can see that it is associated with Windows OS and paths that are too long.  I am using windows, and this is part of an R markdown chunk, but the chunk name is 24 characters (so within the limit) and the R markdown file name is short - also, the error only occurs when I run the above code, which is just part of the code in that chunk.  I can't see how adding the zoom options makes something too long, since they are supposed to be valid arguments?

Any insights as to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

**Update:**

It seems my mistake was not specifying the argument name for `tileOptions` - also `freezeAtZoom` is not necessary to specify when the maximum zoom limit is already specified for the map tiles (in fact if both are specified, the unclustered markers also show up on the map).

The code below works:

```
# Create the interactive map:
myleaflet <- leaflet() %>% 
  # Add open street map (default base layer)
  addTiles(options = tileOptions(maxZoom = 12)) %>% 
  # Add transformed shapefile of regions
  addPolygons(data = regions, weight = 5, col = "black") %>% 
  # Add markers for case residence with descriptive labels:
  addMarkers(lng = mydata$home_long,
             lat = mydata$home_lat,
             popup = paste("ID: ", mydata$id, "<br/>",
                           "Link: ", mydata$links, "<br/>", 
                           "Clade: ", mydata$wgs_cluster), 
             clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) 

# View the map:
myleaflet
```

Since the first option in `addTiles()` is `map` I suppose that it was previously interpreting the `tileOptions` argument as a file path to a map, but I would be interested to know if there are other interpretations, since the traceback showed the problem with the file path length was in saving to html, not importing / reading a file.

Comment: Great job coming back to answer & edit your question - I'm sure if it happened to you, it will happen to someone else in future!